# Preventing function (or decorator) from being nested

Tags: python

I've got some code in a decorator that I only want run once. Many other functions (utility and otherwise) will be called later down the line, and I want to ensure that other functions that may have this decorator aren't accidentally used way down in the nest of function calls.

I also want to be able to check, at any point, whether or not the current code has been wrapped in the decorator or not.

I've written this, but I just wanted to see if anyone else can think of a better/more elegant solution than checking for the (hopefully!) unique function name in the stack.

```
import inspect

def my_special_wrapper(fn):
    def my_special_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        """ Do some magic, only once! """
        # Check we've not done this before
        for frame in inspect.stack()[1:]:  # get stack, ignoring current!
            if frame[3] == 'my_special_wrapper':
                raise StandardError('Special wrapper cannot be nested')
        # Do magic then call fn
        # ...
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return my_special_wrapper

def within_special_wrapper():
    """ Helper to check that the function has been specially wrapped """
    for frame in inspect.stack():
        if frame[3] == 'my_special_wrapper':
            return True
    return False

@my_special_wrapper
def foo():
    print within_special_wrapper()
    bar()
    print 'Success!'

@my_special_wrapper    
def bar():
    pass

foo()
```

Comment: I think this sounds like a case where your design needs to be rethought. Fix this at a design, not a technical level. The kind of hackery you are doing here is fragile and incredibly unusual behaviour that is likely to confuse readers of the code.

Comment: I don't think it should. The wrapper adds logic for a database transaction, handling start/commit, and deadlock retries etc. Using it as a decorator is perfect. Transactions can't be nested, so I need to throw an error if that situation occurs.

Comment: Fair enough, that sounds reasonably legitimate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of using a global for this task - in what I believe is a relatively safe way:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from functools import wraps

_within_special_context = False

@contextmanager
def flag():
    global _within_special_context
    _within_special_context = True
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        _within_special_context = False


#I'd argue this would be best replaced by just checking the variable, but
#included for completeness.
def within_special_wrapper():
    return _within_special_context


def my_special_wrapper(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def internal(*args, **kwargs):
        if not _within_special_context:
            with flag():
                ...
                f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise Exception("No nested calls!")
    return internal

@my_special_wrapper
def foo():
    print(within_special_wrapper())
    bar()
    print('Success!')

@my_special_wrapper
def bar():
    pass

foo()
```

Which results in:

```
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gareth/Development/so/test.py", line 39, in <module>
    foo()
  File "/Users/gareth/Development/so/test.py", line 24, in internal
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gareth/Development/so/test.py", line 32, in foo
    bar()
  File "/Users/gareth/Development/so/test.py", line 26, in internal
    raise Exception("No nested calls!")
Exception: No nested calls!
```

Using a context manager ensures that the variable is unset. You could just use `try/finally`, but if you want to modify the behaviour for different situations, the context manager can be made to be flexible and reusable.

Comment: Yeah I think this is the way forward, I'm liking it!

Comment: Yeah. In this case the use of globals makes sense as you *want* to lock this stuff out *globally*. Obviously, you could use attributes on classes (for example) in other cases where global state isn't appropriate.

Comment: Use of the context manager is definitely the best way. As to use of a function - that is something that might be useful in future, and makes less likely accidentally setting/unsetting the flag.

Comment: That's great. I originally wanted to try and implement something that's not global, but due to the beauty of no threading or concurrency, this solution is simple and elegant. Thanks!

Comment: It would appear that even within the context manager, we need to use a `try/finally` to catch any exceptions and ensure the flag is re-set!

Comment: @MichaelWaterfall Indeed you do - it's not that you need to within the context manager (as that is what a context manager naturally does), but rather, it's needed because of the use of a function with the `contextlib.contextmanager()` decorator to construct the context manager.

Comment: @Lattyware: Ah okay, I understand. I was confused at first as I thought that was what the context manager was supposed to do. Then I realised it was the use of the decorator and function! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Lattyware: Will the global `_within_special_context` flag not have threading issues? (It's all run in a Django/Gunicorn environment)

Comment: @Lattyware: Thoughts on storing the `_within_special_context` flag in the `threading.local()` object, to ensure it's safe in a multithreaded environment?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution is to have `special_wrapper` set a global flag, and just skip its magic if the flag is set.

This is about the only good use of a global variable - to allow a single piece of code to store information that is only used within that code, but which needs to survive the life of execution in that code.

It doesn't need to be set in global scope. The function could set the flag on itself, for example, or on any object or class, as long as nothing else will touch it.

As noted by Lattyware in comments, you'll want to use either a try/except, or perhaps even better, a context manager to ensure the variable is unset.

Update: If you need the wrapped code to be able to check if it is wrapped, then provide a function which returns the value of the flag. You might want to wrap it all up with a class for neatness.

Update 2: I see you're doing this for transaction management. There are probably already libraries which do this. I strongly recommend that you at least look at their code.

Comment: I just edited the question to add the other thing which I needed (and forgot to add at first, sorry!), and that was a function `within_special_wrapper`, that can detect whether the current code is contained in this special wrapper. Would this still be feasible with the global flag? I think this was what stopped me from pursuing the global variable thing.

Comment: @MichaelWaterfall Just check the value of the variable.

Comment: Hmm, that's true. I guess I'm thinking of potential concurrency issues, but with Django and gunicorn, I think that's moot.

Comment: @MichaelWaterfall It's worth noting that there is a potential issue with exceptions causing the flag to never be unset - make sure to do it within a `try`/`finally` block so that it always gets executed (or make a context manager).

Answer (score 1):

While my solution technically works, it requires a manual reset of the decorator, but you could very well modify things such that the outermost function is instead a class (with the instances being the wrappers of the decorated functions passed to it in `__init__`), and have `reset()` being called in `__exit__()`, which would then allow you to use the `with` statement to create the decorator to be usable only once within the context. Also note that it requires Python 3 due to the `nonlocal` keyword, but that can easily be adapted to 2.7 with a dict in place of the flag variable.

```
def once_usable(decorator):
    "Apply this decorator function to the decorator you want to be usable only once until it is reset."

    def outer_wrapper():
        flag = False

        def inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal flag
            if not flag:
                flag = True
                return decorator(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                print("Decorator currently unusable.") # raising an Error also works

        def decorator_reset():
            nonlocal flag
            flag = False

        return (inner_wrapper, decorator_reset)

    return outer_wrapper()
```

Testing:

```
>>> def a(aa):
    return aa*2

>>> def b(bb):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Decorated.")
        return bb(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

>>> dec, reset = once_usable(b)
>>> aa = dec(a)
>>> aa(22)
Decorated.
44
>>> aaa = dec(a)
Decorator currently unusable.
>>> reset()
>>> aaa = dec(a)
>>> aaa(11)
Decorated.
22
```

Comment: @Lattyware True enough, I just came up with this first and didn't feel like rewriting it as a class to properly implement a context manager. Made a note about the possibility of using a context manager for that in my answer, though.